# VBA copying cells if got a value in it

Tags: vba, excel

I wanna write a macro which copy the 1 cells to another sheet if they contain some value.

Table:
[image: Table]

Expectation:
[image: Table i Want]

So far I tried this but it copy only last cell from sheet1 to first cell in sheet 2

```
Sub CopyBasedonSheet1()
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    Sheet1LastRow = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Sheet2LastRow = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    For j = 1 To Sheet1LastRow
        For i = 1 To Sheet2LastRow
            If Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(j, 2).Value = "a" Then
                Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(i, 1).Value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(j, 1).Value
            Else
            End If
        Next i
    Next j
End Sub
```

Comment: Probably your Sheet2LastRow is 1 at the start of your run. Therefore only 1 step happens. In this case you only need 1 loop. Remove the `i` loop and place `i = i+1` in your if statement.

Comment: i tried to creat 8 rows with random text and it all change to last cell in sheet 1. so i get only C,C,C,C,C,C, also i need to check whole document not only 10 or 15 rows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do it with one loop, because when you have a row from the first sheet, there is only 1 place where you want to copy it, not many:

```
Sub CopyBasedonSheet1()
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    Sheet1LastRow = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    i = 1
    For j = 1 To Sheet1LastRow
        If Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(j, 2).Value = "a" Then
            Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(i, 1).Value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(j, 1).Value
            Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(i, 2).Value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(j, 2).Value
            i = i + 1
        End If
    Next j
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you may try a different approach altogether which is faster also...

```
Sub CopyData()
Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
Dim x, y()
Dim i As Long, j As Long
Set ws1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
Set ws2 = Sheets("Sheet2")
x = ws1.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Value
ReDim y(1 To Application.CountIf(ws1.Columns(2), "a"), 1 To 2)
j = 1
For i = 1 To UBound(x, 1)
    If x(i, 2) = "a" Then
        y(j, 1) = x(i, 1)
        y(j, 2) = x(i, 2)
        j = j + 1
    End If
Next i
ws2.Range("A:B").Clear
ws2.Range("A1").Resize(UBound(y, 1), 2).Value = y
End Sub
```